# Having trouble changing the speed of a rectangle

Tags: java, netbeans, game-physics

So the rectangle on my game moves at a speed of one, but I cant change it to 0.5 of 1/2, anyone have any idea how I can slow it down?

```
    if(bounce1){ball.x += 1, ball.y += 1;}
    if(bounce2){ball.x -= 1, ball.y -= 1;}
    if(bounce3){ball.y += 1, ball.x -= 1;}
```

Comment: You're showing us positions rather than speeds. Are you positions by any chance defined as integers?

Comment: What is `ball`? a Point object? If so, make it a `Point2D`. No, you won't be able to display fractional pixels, but the physics will remain fractional. Regardless, *strongly* consider improving this question by providing more pertinent details and code. To help improve your question please have a look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's an abbreviated version of his wonderful longer post on [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 1):

You should elaborate on your project structure and question. I'm guessing your problem is arising because your variables 'ball.x" and "ball.y" are integer type which can not take on values that are half-integers (i.e. 0.5 or 1/2). You should go back and change those variables to doubles. That should fix your problem from my hunch. Again, you should elaborate on your code to make it easier to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A way to change the speed of the ball without interfering with the 1 value would be changing the refresh rate of the game. If you use a timer object to update the position you could simply change the int value.

```
Timer tm = new Timer(this, 8);
```

The object above creates a timer that refreshes every 8 ms. Changing the int will increase or speed up the refresh rate.